# Where method if condition is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does it return empty array or nil if condition is false? 
For example:

```
@result=Result.where(:test_id=>test_id, :user_id => current_user.id).first
```

if there is no result with such test_id and user_id.

I just don't get, I thought first option, but this returns nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is constructed in two parts, the first part returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which is *essentially* an array):

```
 @result_array = Result.where(:test_id=>test_id, :user_id => current_user.id)

 > @result_array.class
  => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

*which is empty (shows as `[]`) if there are no results.*

The second returns the first item, **or** (if it's the empty array) `nil`:

```
> (1..10).first
 => 1

> [].first
 => nil

@first_or_nil = @result = @result_array.first
```

I recommend typing these type of commands in the rails console to see what the results.

Comment: I think first part returns 'ActiveRecord::Relation'

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you may use like this code.

```
@result=Result.where(:test_id=>test_id).(:user_id => current_user.id).first
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't respond to question, what returns method if nothing found.

Comment: you can check the result with @result.count method. It gives 0 if non records found.

Comment: But for some reason it returned nil instead of empty array, and such syntax worked well in other cases, so that is not the reason. I wonder why then?

Answer (score 0):

Thy to use #bang with method .first`!`
For example:

```
@result=Result.where(:test_id=>test_id, :user_id => current_user.id).first!
```

It should return the first element whit ruby will meet in table "results".
It should help.

Comment: Won't this throw an error if the where part finds no results? (rather than `nil`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple query...

```
@result=current_user.results.find_by_test_id(:test_id)
```